# ¿Se puede ejecutar un programa escrito en Java SE en un servidor para que una web lea datos dinámicos generados por él?

Tags: java, java-ee, servidor, restful

Estoy creando un programa escrito en Java SE que lo que hace es recolectar datos de diferentes webs y almacenarlos en una lista.

Quiero saber si es posible ejecutar ese programa en un servidor y mantenerlo activo de forma perpetua para que una aplicación cliente o una web lea las listas dinámicas de datos que crea el programa.

Estoy empezando con Java EE y no estoy seguro que con él se pueda lograr esto que propongo de tener un programa ejecutándose de forma perpetua para compartir los datos dinámicos que obtiene a aplicaciones cliente mediante Restful o EJBs.

Si lo que propongo es posible me podríais aclarar con que tecnología java debo implementarlo y en que tipo de servidor alojarlo.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor lee [ask], tu pregunta parece basada en opiniones y eso sería motivo de cierre

Answer (score 0):

Con containers JEE cambia el paradigma, no tienes un "programa". Lo que se ejecuta es el container que invoca a las clases (servlets, EJBs) que tu hayas definido.

Si has diseñado bien tu programa (independencia de la lógica de programa de la presentación) debería ser sencillo montar servlets o EJBs que accedan y usen tu capa de lógica. Si no está bien diseñado, aprenderás una valiosa lección sobre porqué te interesa diseñar bien tus programas.

Una alternativa a usar un container es agregar alguna librería como Jetty, puede ser más sencillo para empezar pero también más limitado. Y tampoco te soluciona el problema si tu programa no está bien diseñado.

Comment: Es decir. Si he entendido bien. Mi programa debo meterlo en un container y para acceder  a el lo haría mediante ejbs.¿ El programa una vez metido en un container puedo subirlo a un servidor comp glassfish?